# Condicional operadores

Tags: c#

tengo un codigo echo para mi condicional pero al ejecutarlo no me realiza la acción.

```
 if ((Rutinaria.SelectedItem.Value != " ") && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtReferencia.Text.TrimEnd()))
            {
                   this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&Prueba=5&sDatos="+sDatos));
            }
            else if ((Rutinaria.SelectedItem.Value != " ") && (txtReferencia.Text != " "))
            {  
                   this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&Prueba=6&sDatos="+sDatos));        
            }
            else {
                this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&Prueba=1&sDatos="+sDatos)); 
            }
```

Al final lo he modificado a mi manera. No lose si estará programado de la mejor manera pero me ha funcionado así.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que el valor que tienes seleccionado en Rutinaria es un espacio en blanco(" ") y no uno vacio ("")?

Comment: En primer lugar txtReferencia.Text no deberia darte null porque es un componente creado, puede estar vacio pero no null. Segundo en SelectedItem deberia evaluar que no sea null, o el index mayor a 0 y no evaluar una cadena de texto con un espacio en blanco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba usando la funcion de string para evaluar vacios y nulos, ademas de pasarle trim a los campos

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Rutinaria.SelectedItem.Value) 

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReferencia.Text.Trim())
```

Comment: En mi condicional necesito pasarle dos valores. En cada If los tengo opuestos y al final tengo else ya que son tres diferentes condiciones.

Comment: y puedes combinarla como necesites para cada situacion, el punto del código es que limpies de espacios con el trim siempre tus  strings y además verifiques que no sean nulos sus valores, son validaciones tipicas para este tipo de datos.

Comment: Ya lo he modificado y los string no me los pasa correctamente

Comment: Lo he modificado el código a mi manera y me ha funcionado. No se si estará bien programado, igualmente gracias.